# Scikit Spectral Clustering fails to classify concentric circles

Tags: scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, spectral-density

Here is some code to set up the clustering problem:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# KMeans
# # Class=2
# Center(2.5,2.5), r1 = 2, r2 = 1
X1 = np.zeros(500*4)
X2 = np.zeros(500*4)

r1 = 2; r2 = 1; a = 2.5; b = 2.5 # generate circle

h = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)
X1[:1000] = np.cos(h) * r1 + a + noise
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)
X2[:1000] = np.sin(h) * r1 + a + noise

h = np.random.uniform(0, 2*np.pi, 1000)
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)
X1[1000:] = np.cos(h) * r2 + b + noise
noise = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, 1000)
X2[1000:] = np.sin(h) * r2 + b + noise

X = np.array([X1,X2]).T

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
plt.scatter(X[:,0],X[:,1])
```

From the following image, we assume that there are two clusters. All points in the inner circle should belong to one, and the outer circle should belong to another.

[image: the image]

By scikit-learn, we have this code with RBF kernel:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,assign_labels='kmeans', affinity='rbf',random_state=0).fit(X)
print(clustering.labels_)

plt.figure(figsize=(4,4))
X_C1 = np.array([X[i,:] for i in range(len(clustering.labels_)) if clustering.labels_[i] == 1])
X_C2 = np.array([X[i,:] for i in range(len(clustering.labels_)) if clustering.labels_[i] == 0])
plt.scatter(X_C1[:,0],X_C1[:,1],c="blue")
plt.scatter(X_C2[:,0],X_C2[:,1],c="red")
plt.show()
```

But it seems that the spectral clustering doesn't work (as bad KMeans clustering). So what is the problem here?

[image: By scikit-learn]

Comment: I write spectral clustering and find that small sigma in Gaussian similarity matrix will just give good clustering. No problem.

Answer (score 1):

The default `gamma=1.0` parameter is not high enough for this application.

Try `gamma=6.0`:

```py
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering

clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2, gamma=6.0).fit(X)

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=clustering.labels_)
plt.show()
```

[image: Two concentric circles are plotted on a grid. The inner circle is yellow, and the outer circle is violet. A higher gamma value solved this problem.]

Comment: It does work well. So is the gamma equals to $1/\sigma$ as in Gaussian similarity matrix (before putting it into Laplacian matrix and do eigendecomposition) $w=e^{-||x_i-x_j||^2/(2\sigma^2}$? If it is, do we need to specify how many $x_j$ are used to construct the quiet sparse similarity matrix (by KNN) or do we just need to use all features (all $x_j$) to construct a very compact similarity matrix?

Comment: I think the first part is close (I don't remember if $\gamma = 1/\sigma$ or if $\gamma = 1/2\sigma^{2}$, e.g. [see Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_basis_function_kernel)). I'm having trouble understanding the second part of the question: `rbf` and `nearest_neighbors` are two different ways of constructing the similarity matrix, and I believe both use all features.

Comment: In think in the source code, the rbf kernel does not use all the #n data to construct. Instead, it first uses KNN to find nearest data points $x_a,x_b,..$ to, say, $x_i$, and then constructs the rbf on those nearest data. In this way, the RBF can be quite sparse. We can definitely use all data to compute the rbf tho.