# How to perform Spectral Clustering on 3 circles dataset with three different classes

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, cluster-analysis

I want to perform spectral clustering on the 3 circles dataset that I have generated using make circles as shown in the figure. All the three circles are of different classes.

[image: Generating 3 circles]

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_circles
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pylab as pl
import networkx as nx
X_small, y_small = make_circles(n_samples=(100,200), random_state=3, 
noise=0.07, factor = 0.7)
X_large, y_large = make_circles(n_samples=(100,200), random_state=3, 
noise=0.07, factor = 0.4)
y_large[y_large==1] = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([X_small,X_large]),columns=['x1','x2'])
df['label'] = np.hstack([y_small,y_large])
df.label.value_counts()
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='x1',y='x2',hue='label',style='label',palette="bright")
```

Comment: Also, it's not very clear what you want to plot

Comment: I have made some changes can you please look into the question again @StupidWolf.

Comment: This question already has an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470814/8044858 (just change the `SpectralClustering()` parameters). For example, in my experiments, `SpectralClustering(gamma=1000)` found the 3 clusters with `n_samples=(1000,2000)` and `factor = 0.1` / `factor = 0.6` in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't flag this question as duplicate (the [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67454284/scikit-spectral-clustering-fails-to-classify-concentric-circles/67470814) has no accepted answer), here is a working example of Spectral Clustering on 3 circles using your code:

```
X_small, y_small = make_circles(n_samples=(1000,2000), random_state=3, 
noise=0.07, factor = 0.1)
X_large, y_large = make_circles(n_samples=(1000,2000), random_state=3, 
noise=0.07, factor = 0.6)
y_large[y_large==1] = 2
df = pd.DataFrame(np.vstack([X_small,X_large]),columns=['x1','x2'])
df['label'] = np.hstack([y_small,y_large])
df.label.value_counts()
sns.scatterplot(data=df,x='x1',y='x2',hue='label',style='label',palette="bright")
```

Then adapt the slightly modified 3 circles dataset (added samples and spread the circles) to the code of this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67470814/8044858):

```
x1 = np.expand_dims(df['x1'].values,axis=1)
x2 = np.expand_dims(df['x2'].values,axis=1)
X = np.concatenate((x1,x2),axis=1)
y = df['label'].values

from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering

clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=3, gamma=1000).fit(X)

colors = ['r','g','b']
colors = np.array([colors[label] for label in clustering.labels_])
plt.scatter(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1], c=colors[y==0], marker='X')
plt.scatter(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1], c=colors[y==1], marker='o')
plt.scatter(X[y==2, 0], X[y==2, 1], c=colors[y==2], marker='*')
plt.show()
```

The `np.expand_dims(...,axis=1)` is necessary to create the dimension along which to concatenate features with `np.concatenate()` (we initially have 1D vectors, and we don't want to concatenate along the existing initial dimension which is the samples index dimension). Each `plt.scatter()` line plots the points of a single true data class (hence the `y==y_true` index selection) using the associated `marker`, the colors indicating the class provided by the clustering.

Resulting dataset:

[image: Dataset]

Resulting clusters:

[image: Clusters]

**Edit:** to use different markers to identify true classes (colors already indicating the clustering classes), as asked by OP in the comments. We unfortunately cannot use an array for markers (as for colors) to produce the plot in a single line of code, this is because `marker` does not accept a list as input (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51810842/8044858)).

**Edit2:** added motivation for the use of `np.expand_dims(...,axis=1)` and some explanation for the `plt.scatter()` lines, as asked by OP in the comments.

Comment: I need a plot where points in original classes are represented by different symbols and points in clusters are represented by different colours @Blupon

Comment: @Ytt the code was edited to denote true classes with markers, and clustering classes with colors.

Comment: Can you please explain to me why you have used np.expand_dims and np.concatenate? and also I am not able to understand how you have plotted the figure.

Comment: @Ytt I added the explanations you asked for in the answer.